# CALL in FOR breaks FOR

Tags: batch-file

Consider the following batch file:

```
@echo off

set ORACLESERVER=ORAOP09
set ORACLEDB=OraDb11g_home1

set ORACLESERVICES.1 = OracleVssWriter%ORACLESERVER%
set ORACLESERVICES.2 = OracleDBConsole%ORACLESERVER%
set ORACLESERVICES.3 = Oracle%ORACLEDB%TNSListener
set ORACLESERVICES.4 = OracleService%ORACLESERVER%

AT > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo FATAL: THIS SCRIPT MUST BE RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR!
    pause
    exit
)

echo Stopping services...
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=.=" %%A IN ('SET ORACLESERVICES.') DO sc stop %%B > NUL
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=.=" %%A IN ('SET ORACLESERVICES.') DO call:check %%B

:check
    sc query %1 | find /I "State" | find /I "STOPPED"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call:check %1

echo All services stopped successfully!
pause
exit
```

In the 2nd FOR statement, when ERRORLEVEL = 0, the rest of the file runs, instead of going to the next FOR item. How can I make this work as intended?

Thanks!

Comment: you need `goto :eof` in your subroutine (it works as a `return` statement)

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting that batch files have no control structure. You must explicitly terminate each subroutine by falling off the end of the batch file or via `exit /b`. The same goes for the body of the batch file (to avoid ploughing into the body of the first subroutine).

Also, you have indefinite recursion in your `check` subroutine that will quickly exhaust `cmd`'s nesting ability. Use plain `goto`.

So:

```
....................
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=.=" %%A IN ('SET ORACLESERVICES.') DO call:check %%B

echo All services stopped successfully!
pause
exit
rem If you change your mind and remove the exit above, you'll need this:
goto :EOF

:check
    sc query %1 | find /I "State" | find /I "STOPPED"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto check
    goto :EOF
    rem Technically you don't need the above line when this subroutine
    rem is at the end of the batch file, but it's a good idea to put it
    rem in anyway for clarity and to simplify future modifications
```